# python requests <Response [403]> Even after adding useragent

Tags: python

I am getting `<Response [403]>` on a get request even after adding user agent header

This is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.malacards.org/categories/blood_disease_list'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers)

print(r)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some more information about your issue so people can help you. A 403 error simply means the access is forbidden and using a user-agent is by far not the only step into getting the right response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the headers as a kwarg:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The [signature of `get`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/a4c18cd733f97b5659a29589432d8a39e7a0de87/requests/api.py#L63) is:

```
def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
```

If you don't pass it as a kwarg, Python assumes you meant that `params = headers`.